# Laravel + Vue.js (axios) using web route - Unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

i have my route/web.php like follow:

```
Route::prefix('espace')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('conversation/{id}', [MessageController::class, 'get_message'])->name('conversation.message');
    Route::post('searchUser', [UserController::class, 'search'])->name('user.search');
    Route::post('sendMessage', [MessageController::class, 'send_message'])->name('message.send');
    Route::post('getConversation', [MessageController::class, 'all_conversation'])->name('conversation.all');
});
```

i tried to use them on vue js using axios;

in my blade i have this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

in my bootsrapt.js:
let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

```
window.axios = require('axios');
if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

my kernel.php:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

i already have my csrf token on request

[image: headers],

the user is logged in, but on request i got error 401 "Unauthenticated"

Answer (score 0):

X-CSRF-TOKEN - is not token for authentication,
when your route protected 'auth' middleware using cookies for authentication

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what should i do